# How to use Web Recorder's "File Download" command to download a file which needs authentication?

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am working on Automation Anywhere RPA platform to automate below process -
1. Login to a website using Username and Password.
2. Navigate to a page on that site.
3. Download a file from that page.

How to download a file in the same session that was created by the first step ?

I was able to successfully write a task with first two steps. For the third one, I tried Web Recorder's "Download File" command, which doesn't execute under the authenticated session created when the first step runs to login into the site.

The "Download File" command runs without any error but the file downloaded is not a valid file. When I opened the downloaded file in noted, I noticed that the content nothing but html response to an un-authenticated request to the file-download url.

I expect the "File Download" command is run under the authenticated web session created by the first step of the task (which is entering Username and Password).

Comment: How does the user downloads the file? I assume he/she will click on a button or a link? Object clone it and click on it like a user.

Comment: Thanks @KhaledMostafaMe. I thought using "Download File" command would be a cleaner approach. What is the use case for "Download File" command then ?

Comment: You're welcome, The Download command works for the file that can be accessed without authentication (To make it easy for the user to download any file directly by the link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the download requires an authenticated web session, download the file using the left mouse click on the download button or the link.

Download command works for the file that can be accessed without authentication (To make it easy for the user to download any file directly by the link).